# How to integrate ADFS with web page

Tags: web, single-sign-on, adfs

I am making a webpage that need SSO feature with ADFS. I need to know:
1, web server must be IIS or it is also fine with nginx/apache
2, It should be the front end talk to ADFS or backend talk to ADFS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture and environment are not important.

What is important is that the architecture implements one of the ADFS supported protocols i.e.

- SAML 2.0
- WS-Fed
- OpenID Connect / OAuth (ADFS 4.0)

Your application needs to support a client side stack for one of the above.

e.g. for .NET, you could use WIF or OWIN OpenID Connect or OWIN WS-Fed or OWIN SAML.

For Java, you could use Spring Security (SAML).

Comment: thanks a lot, above information is just what I need. I am a Devops, and we will need java and SAML. we are building a web site that need to link to client's existing ADFS (SSO). Would you please advise what information do I need from the client in order to do so , and how can I use java code to connect their ADFS?

Comment: You need a SAML stack - http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html. Then you need to configure the client side and ADFS. Most of what you need is contained in the ADFS metadata (ask for that). That contains endpoints, certificates etc.  e.g http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RC3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html

Comment: Thanks again @nzpcmad , yes, I am just using spring-security-saml. My web page may need a login box in the web page ,Any advise for how to confige the login-box and it will send auth request to ADFS server after click "Login"?

Comment: The way it should work is that as soon as you hit a protected page, spring should redirect to the ADFS login page.